DNS server default gateway set up
I'm trying to set up a DNS server on my Windows Server 2019 (VM on VMware)
In the instructions I'm following, the first step is to set up a static IP address by editing the Ethernet (disable IPv6 and configure IPv4 by entering the IP address manually). Within that window, you also need to put in a default gateway, which when I have done this set up previously, I used ipconfig to get the value.
Now, with a new machine, I can see that my default gateway is in fe80::x:x:x:x:x format, which I can't use.
Could you advise me how to get a IPv4 value for a default gateway?
Explain to me like I'm 5, I'm only starting, thanks ;)
I tried taking my IP address and putting 1 as the last value, which didn't work.
I don't knwo why I had a different default gateway address this time - only thing i did was to install my VM on a different disc within the same PC.
+is there a mock value I can use - this is to train only

The default gateway in the fe80::x:x:x:x:x format is IPv6. Make sure that you have IPv4 enabled and then use ipconfig to look for the IPv4 gateway underneath the Ethernet adapter line. If there is no such gateway, manually set one with your network's IP range. You can alo use a mock gateway for training if you'd like.

Thanks Vishrut.
Could you expand on how I can enable IPv4 and how to manually set one with my network's IP range?
